# Restoring Remix Files

Tags: google-chrome, ethereum, solidity, restore, remix

A few days ago my Remix files from both browsers that I use (Brave and Chrome) no longer show my .sol files under the "contracts" folder. I'm confused as to how they may have been erased in that I did not clear any browser data. How would I restore these .sol files?

When I go to Developer Tools>Application>Local Storage, I see the keys/values pairs but I don't
know what to do with them. Supposedly in the browser console I can plug a string into a function to restore them? If someone could help guide me how to go about this I'd really appreciate it!

Thank you.